# SAP external command using lftp over sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I need to connect to the EDI server and pick up the data via sftp. This is an unusual ftp server. This is a special server that erases files after reading. We dismissed the initial idea of mounting the sftp folder to the linux file system, since the mv command did not have time to copy the files. I don't want to use a username and password for authentication, but I want to use an ssh key. I generated it and sent it to my colleagues. Next, I run this script on OS level:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=x.x.x.x
PORT=2022
USER=TEST_USER_NAME
KEYFILE=/home/srvadm/.ssh/id_rsa
REMOTE_DIR=From FM
LOCAL_DIR=/output/dev/

eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add $KEYFILE

lftp -u $USER sftp://$HOST:$Port "set sftp:connect-program 'sh -a -x'"<<EOF
cd $REMOTE_DIR
lcd $LOCAL_DIRECTORY
mget *.csv
bye
EOF
```

And I got the error:

```
Agent pid 18964
Identity added: /home/srvadm/.ssh/id_rsa (srvadm@myserver-2024-02-08)
open: GetPass() failed -- assume anonymous login
cd: Login failed: Password required
ls: ls -l: Login failed: Password required
mget: *.csv: Login failed: Password required
ls: ls -l: Login failed: Password required
External program terminated with exit code 1
```

Why is the remote server asking for a password? How to avoid this?

versions: LFTP | Version 4.9.2 Linux version 5.14.21-150400.24.33-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils; SUSE Linux Enterpris

I tried the

```
    lftp -u $USER:bla-bla-bla-password
```

command, it works, but it blocks the user on the server side, although key authentication is in the user settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working solution for me:

```
SFTP_COMMAND="sftp -o Port=$PORT -o IdentityFile=$KEYFILE -o BatchMode=yes $USER@$HOST"

$SFTP_COMMAND <<EOF
cd $REMOTE_DIR
lcd $LOCAL_DIR
mget *.csv
bye
EOF
```